# Should I dismiss keyboard before dismissing the view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two `UIViewControllers`, on modally presented over the other. The first controller is orientated in landscape, and the modal view is presented in portrait.

When dismissing the modal view, the view animates to reveal the landscape view below. If the keyboard is visible on the modal view at this time, it will suddenly attach itself to the left or right side of the screen to match the orientation of the soon-to-be active viewController.

Is there a way to let the keyboard disappear in the same orientation as the disappearing viewController? Or should I perhaps dismiss the keyboard **before** dismissing the modal view controller? In that case, what would be the best approach?

I do have an action for when the user clicks 'close'. I can there check if any objects are firstResponder, and start a timer for ~0.4 seconds before dismissing.. But it would obviously create a kind of delay that wouldn't feel all that natural.. I'd prefer a way to let the keyboard stay attached to the same orientation as the dismissing view.

This is happening:

[image: Keyboard dismissing wrong]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best practice would be to dismiss the keyboard before dismissing your modal ViewController. The keyboard is presented over your content and should be removed first before removing other items in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Ah yes. I thought I would have to 'pause' the dismissal of the modal view in order to wait for the keyboard to exit the view, but simply adding `[textField resignFirstResponder];` right before `[self dismiss...];` did the trick. It now dismisses before the dismissal.